# Determining whether points are collinear

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(1,1)(3,9)(6,21)$

The way I figured that this should be solved is by finding the slope of: 
$(1,1)(3,9)$

Then, $(3,9)(6,21)$

Finally $(1,1)(6,21)$

Which are 4, 4,and 4 respectively. 
So I assume that they are collinear.

Am I correct? And if not, please provide me with an explanation as to what needs to be done to find the answer rather than a direct answer.

Comment: $\dfrac{21-1}{6-1} = \dfrac{20}{5} = 4$ not $20$.

Comment: Put down the wrong number. Sorry. Will edit

Comment: Two slopes will do.

Comment: How about some linear algebra and a calculating some determinant?

Comment: To be correct, you need to give an answer to your question: "Are those three points collinear?"

Comment: Well they all have the same slope so I assume that this means that they are collinear..?

Comment: Yes, if AB and BC have same slopes then the points A, B, C are collinear. Finding the third slope AC is redundant.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, I am very sorry for the incorrect solution, you need NOT find $y$ intercept.  First you find slope of $AB$, next you find slope of $BC$ and we see that slope of $AB$=slope of $BC$ and since $B$ is common to both the line segments, it proves that the three points are collinear

Answer (score 1):

What you checked is ok; in plane geometry if any two slopes from the point pairs are necessarily same, it is sufficient to conclude collinearity.

Answer (score 0):

As you're given three points yes it's correct.
There are more ways to find co-linearity:
Determinant method: If
$$\det\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1 \\
  3 & 9 & 1 \\    
 6 & 21 & 1 
\end{array}\right|=0$$
It is colinear.
Using distance formula: if your points are A,B and C then,
$$AB^2+BC^2=AC^2\ \ or\ \ AC^2+BC^2=AB^2\ \ or\ \ AB^2+AC^2=BC^2$$
means it is colinear

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. It is sufficient to calculate only two slopes to decide that three points are collinear.